# ESD protection for RS485 with power bus, without earth

Tags: grounding, esd, rs485

On my board there is a 4-pin connector as follow:

1. +24V DC (up to 6A)
2. RS485/A
3. RS485/B
4. GND

On the system there is no real earth, because there are no metallic parts (chassis, case, structure, etc...).

I'm going to protect the board as follow:

- SM712 between I/O lines and the "virtual" earth (see below)
- unidirectional TVS with 24V stand-off voltage between power and "virtual" earth
- two Schottky in antiparallel between GND and "virtual" earth

The "virtual" earth is nothing but a large PCB trace that runs along the board edge (where the connectors are placed) and is connected to the actual GND at the power input connector through an inductor.

The idea is to provide an easier way for the spike's current to flow instead of enter inside board.

Here a schematic that summarize:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLbbwb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

What do you think about?

Comment: So you don't have earth ground for common, but if everything is referenced to the GND input, so that is your common ground. All those inductors and diodes (L1,D1,D2) will make it worse for the protection, so remove them and replace with short circuit on the schematic.

Comment: Ok, but it makes sense to keep the trace separated along the board edge but the power input?

Comment: Are you suggesting to connect using tiny traces the GND to this large "dummy" earth trace?

Comment: No, tiny traces are also bad. As wide as possible. Ideally there should be a ground plane.

Comment: @Justme, sorry I don't get the point. If I place a ground plane (GND) any spike that comes on the GND wire will spread across the whole board, doesn't it?

Comment: What are you trying to protect? Without knowing that your circuit is meaningless.

Comment: @Andyaka, on the board there is an MCU, a power supply, some mosfet. Please, correct me if I'm wrong, but ESD protection is about the incoming spikes, not what there is on the board (ok, unless there are only connectors and nothing else)

Comment: Adding surge protection is all about protecting vulnerable devices from ESD surges. So that's (a) the surge and (b) the vulnerable devices i.e. two things; the threat and the victim. It's solved analytically and mathematically but now knowing one side of the story gets you nowhere fast.

Comment: Ok, got it. I can't really post the whole schematic from my colleagues, but I can provide the information you need. I.e. the RS485 is connected to the transceiver and then to the MCU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don‘t get tricked into thinking you can control where some voltage or current spikes will flow and where not.

Usually, the ultimate goal of ESD protection is to ensure that the victim (IC) will never get more voltage than it can take.

So your design goal of ESD protection is to use protection devices to kind of **clamp** all signals, GND and VCC together. So if e.g. GND suddenly  goes below -2000V, the other lines must follow. Think of the sensitive IC being *sandwiched* between protection devices.

Further advice: L is useless or even bad. Place the TVS between 24V and GND (explanation above).